Как добавить кнопке несколько событий
Есть кнопка внизу формы
<button class="form-button" type="submit" onclick="setTimeout(function () {location.reload()}, 100);window.print();">Print</button>

при нажатии на которую открывается контекстное меню печати страницы и после отправки на печать, страница перезагружается.
Почему, при нажатии на кнопку, параллельно не записываются данные из формы в mysql? Если из кнопки убираю onclick=""
<button class="form-button" type="submit">Print</button>

то данные в mysql записываются без проблем. Как исправить код, чтобы и данные отправлялись в базу и была возможность отпрвлять страницу на печать? Спасибо.

Можно запросом отправить данные на сервер, параллельно (или последовательно) заняться уже печатью...

С технической стороны нет никаких проблем исправить, если отказаться от того, чтобы пытаться всё впихнуть всё onclick в пользу самостоятельного события и воспользоваться внутри .addEventListener('click', ...) .preventDefault(). Однако вы не учитываете главного, а именно того факта, что должно это работать вообще иначе. 1. вы отправляете форму, 2. вам приходит ответ сервера о удачном добавлении в БД, и уж затем... 3. вывод на печать, и 4. обновление страницы, если оно вам необходимо, поскольку благодаря .preventDefault() мы можем сделать ещё красивше и без перезагрузок.

К кнопке добавьте id:
<button id = "printBtn"></button>

А в скрипте попробуйте так:
 document.getElementById('printBtn')
            .addEventListener('click', () => {
                //сюда все действия при нажатии на кнопку
                window.print()
            })

